# Is it valid to put stylesheets before the closing body tag if using critical CSS in the head?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to follow a Google advice to first load critical CSS inline in the header then load other styles. Some articles advise to load other styles asynchronously with the help of JS. However, I wonder whether I can simply place them before the closing `body` tag. Is it going to affect rendering negatively (taken that the above the fold styles are already loaded)?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      <!-- Critical CSS goes here to display what's above the fold -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" ... >
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it is okay.

Comment: It's invalid. If it is "okay" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Quentin, W3C validation didn't report any errors. What rules does it break?

Comment: Replaced OK with Valid to get rid of that "matter of opinion" thing again and downvoting.

Comment: any reason you want to put it before the closing tag? the main reason you wouldn't is to avoid a flash of unstyled content (FOUT) http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/how-to-prevent-flash-of-unstyled-content-on-your-websites/

Comment: The WHATWG spec has been modified this year to make this kind of rendering optimization allowed: https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/616. The latest W3C spec seems to have ported this change (https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/links.html#body-ok). So it's already valid per WHATWG spec and will be valid soon per W3C one.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn That should be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [HTML5.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) the `<link>` element is only allowed in the `<head>`:

> If the rel attribute is used, the element is restricted to the head element.

(Note also the previous line: "A link element must have a rel attribute".)

But the [HTML5.2 working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/links.html#body-ok) relaxes this requirement:

> Keywords that are body-ok affect whether link elements are allowed in the body. The body-ok keywords defined by this specification are prefetch, and stylesheet.

Comment: HTML 5.0 is dead since October, please don't link to it. The WHATWG spec has been modified this year to make this kind of rendering optimization allowed: https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/616. The latest W3C spec seems to have ported this change (https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/links.html#body-ok). So this restriction is nothing but history now.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn you are right;  I will correct this answer. Thank you.